# how to tell is a string is a stringify'd JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

**For anyone interested, I ended up building a "localstorage with expirations" script here, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/localcache**

What I'm doing: building an extension for Storage, so that the user can do this:

```
localStorage.setThing(key, value)
```

and the user can do the following:

```
localStorage.setThing("key1", 1)
localStorage.setThing("key2", "this is a string")
localStorage.setThing("key3", { prop1: "this is a json obj" })
```

In my setThing method, I'm checking for the typeof for value, and if `typeof value == "object"`, I'm storing it as `localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))`

On the getThing method, I know that the value that makes it into localStorage is always going to be a string.  So, how can I do this?

```
var val = localStorage.getItem("key3")
if (val is a previously JSON.stringify'd object) // <-- ??
    return JSON.parse(val)
```

Do I need to do a regex check on val, and if so, does anyone have a pattern handy which tells me if a string is really a JSON.stringify'd object?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the EAFP - It's easier to ask for forgiveness than it is to get permission) - *pattern* [Grace Hopper], see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to store an object `{isJsonObj:true, jsonObj: jsonObj}`, and check the type is Object, and isJsonObj is true. If either of those are false, then it isn't a json obj (this means you don't have to parse). I realise this means you won't always have a string in there, but it makes it easy to test, and won't carry a large amount of overhead.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to tell if a string is JSON is to run it through a JSON decoder.  If it succeeds, it is JSON :-)   No need for a regex here.

Comment: Just run ``JSON.parse(val)`` directly.  There is no need for the if-statement.  If the parse fails, then *val* wasn't valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this :) so, how do I check if it fails?

Comment: The easiest way to learn the answers to questions like this is to read the docs for *JSON.parse* or to just experiment by running the code -- in this case you will see it throw a *JSONError*.  To learn about catching exceptions, see http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml

Comment: the following is not caught, i.e., I can't use this method for trying to parse.    var test = JSON.parse("3"); // does not throw an error, and I don't want my JS to think that "3" is a previously JSON stringify'd object. might have to do the regex approach

Answer (score 2):

What kind of speed do you need when doing this?
If it isn't a big issue, you could always just try parsing/decoding val, and if it fails, then it isn't a JSON object.

Comment: if I try { var x = JSON.parse("3"); }, it does not throw an error. so, I may have to do the regex approach, since I'll always be trying to parse a string. any other thoughts?  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if variable is stringify right?

```
const obj = {"apple": 1, "banana": 2, "cat": 3}
const stringify_value = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

You can try lodash isString

```
import isString from "lodash/isString"

if(isString(stringify_value)) {
  // the value is stringify
}else{
  // the value is not stringify   
}
```